# Generic equality test

Tags: java, equals

I would like to check if two Java objects are equal. This check should also work for arrays. I wrote this:

```
/** Check if two Java objects are equal. */
private static <T> boolean equal (T a, T b)
{
  if (a == null)
    if (b == null)
      return true;
    else
      if (b.getClass().isArray())
        return Arrays.equals(b, a);
      else
        return b.equals(a);
  else
    if (a.getClass().isArray())
      return Arrays.equals(a, b);
    else
      return a.equals(b);
}
```

But calling `Arrays.equals` fails to compile with the following error:

```
no suitable method found for equals(T,T)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have a read of java.util.Objects#deepEquals;  it implements what you are doing here.  In essence you need to go recursive.  See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Objects.java#Objects.deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29.

Comment: @ChrisK You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @assylias, thank you, however flamingpenguin has that covered.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in `java.util.Arrays.deepEquals0(Object, Object)`

You can see the following code

```
static boolean deepEquals0(Object e1, Object e2) {
    assert e1 != null;
    boolean eq;
    if (e1 instanceof Object[] && e2 instanceof Object[])
        eq = deepEquals ((Object[]) e1, (Object[]) e2);
    else if (e1 instanceof byte[] && e2 instanceof byte[])
        eq = equals((byte[]) e1, (byte[]) e2);
    else if (e1 instanceof short[] && e2 instanceof short[])
        eq = equals((short[]) e1, (short[]) e2);
    else if (e1 instanceof int[] && e2 instanceof int[])
        eq = equals((int[]) e1, (int[]) e2);
    else if (e1 instanceof long[] && e2 instanceof long[])
        eq = equals((long[]) e1, (long[]) e2);
    else if (e1 instanceof char[] && e2 instanceof char[])
        eq = equals((char[]) e1, (char[]) e2);
    else if (e1 instanceof float[] && e2 instanceof float[])
        eq = equals((float[]) e1, (float[]) e2);
    else if (e1 instanceof double[] && e2 instanceof double[])
        eq = equals((double[]) e1, (double[]) e2);
    else if (e1 instanceof boolean[] && e2 instanceof boolean[])
        eq = equals((boolean[]) e1, (boolean[]) e2);
    else
        eq = e1.equals(e2);
    return eq;
}
```

So I think you will need to do something similar.

Comment: I am wondering how efficient this `intanceof` forest will be.

Comment: I think you would have to measure that in your particular use case. I cannot think of a way of doing it more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some casting - like below.  You may need to have some logic to conditionally cast them to int[], float[], Object[], etc.

```
private static <T> boolean equal (T a, T b)
{
  if (a == null)
    if (b == null)
      return true;
    else
      if (b.getClass().isArray())
        return Arrays.equals((Object[])b, (Object[])a);
      else
        return b.equals(a);
  else
    if (a.getClass().isArray())
      return Arrays.equals(a, b);
    else
      return a.equals(b);
}
```

Comment: The second does not need the cast?

Comment: @ceving you are correct.  The posted code is for example only and has not been tested.  I would actually recommend http://stackoverflow.com/a/24531874/348975 in preference to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.equals` doesn't accept any generic type `<T>`.

It only accepts different types of arrays `[]`. See the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Therefore you'd have to cast both `a` and `b` to an array, before passing it to `Arrays.equals` like:

```
Object[] bArr = (Object[])b;
Object[] aArr = (Object[])a;
return Arrays.equals(bArr, aArr);
```

Comment: I have not tried it but I would say, that a cast to Object will loose all overridden equals methods. This means that strings are not equal any more, if they are not stored at the same address.